# How can I move number of objects between two points with random speed?

Tags: unity, c#

In the Hierarchy I have a Cube and the script is attached to the cube.
And I also have in the Hierarchy two spheres as waypoints.

```
public class WP : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] waypoints;
    public float movingSpeed;

    GameObject[] allLines;
    GameObject[] duplicatedPrefabs;

    private void Start()
    {
        allLines = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("FrameLine");

        DuplicatePrefabEffects(allLines.Length);
        duplicatedPrefabs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Duplicated Prefab");
    }

    private void DuplicatePrefabEffects(int duplicationNumber)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < duplicationNumber; i++)
        {
            var go = Instantiate(prefabEffect);
            go.tag = "Duplicated Prefab";
            go.name = "Duplicated Prefab";
        }
    }

    private void MoveDuplicated()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < duplicatedPrefabs.Length; i++)
        {
           duplicatedPrefabs[i].transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pointA.position, pointB.position, movingSpeed *Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
     MoveDuplicated();
    }
}
```

The duplicatedPrefabs are moving very very fast no matter what value I put for movingSpeed and then they are all stuck in the second waypoint and seems like moving on very specific small area on the second waypoint.

What I want to do is to move them smooth slowly between the two waypoints and with random speed range from each object. For example one will move at speed 1 the other on speed 20 third on speed 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use [Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) as though it were [MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html). Lerp just picks a point between two extremes, it doesn't automatically move that picked point unless you change its inputs.

Try this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < duplicatedPrefabs.Length; i++)
{
   duplicatedPrefabs[i].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
                duplicatedPrefabs[i].transform.position,
                pointB.position,
                movementSpeeds[i] * Time.deltaTime
            );
}
```

Two things to note here:

1. This moves the prefabs toward `pointB` from wherever they happen to be. Make sure you're spawning them at `pointA` so they start from the right place.
2. This assumes a parallel array of movement speeds for each object that you've populated in advance, using something like `Random.Range()`